# How to disable initial block download

Tags: bitcoind, protocol, command-line-options

I want to create an original network by forking bitcoind.
I changed `chainparams.cpp` and other programs for loading it.
Then, I set DNS for my seed node.

When I boot my seed node, my seed node tries to download blocks from others.
However, there is only a single seed node(itself). So, I expected that my seed node loads blocks which are pre-located in the local data directory. But, my seed node executes the initial block download process.

In this situation, other nodes cannot sync with my seed node because bitcoind ignores `getheaders` message while initial block download.

To operate a seed node, is there any command options for disabling initial block download?

As an additional question, is there any discussions and best practice for operating seed nodes?

Answer (score 1):

For set up the dns seed node, the parameter can be directly specified in chainparam.cpp if you are using bitcoin source in line that reads as "

vSeeds.push_back(CDNSSeedData("someaddress.com or IP addy", "someaddress.com"));

And  you need to add all the seed node IP address to the A records where  you have your domain name from. You might need to do it on your own if you have a privater server or can use cpanel depending on the scenario at your end. I did it via cpanel as I have domains hosted with siteground.

Comment: I set my seed node in chainparams.cpp. When I boot anther node, the node tries to sync with the seed node. But, the seed node ignores the getheaders message from the another node because the boot node processes the initial block download process. Then, I think that there is need to disable the initial block download process on the seed node. My question is whether there is any disabling method or not.( if there is no method, should I modify the code of the seed node to disable?)